# How can i use a function to condense my code?

Tags: python

fairly new to programming & i know i can use a function to condense this code bc its just mainly text im writing and ive used so many lines already. I've played around with defining my own function etc and i failed.  Anyone know how i can make a function that includes like font size, if i want bold and font face???

This was my most recent attempt at doing it - but it didnt work:

```
def style(x, y, z,):
  return Entry(Point(x,y),"z")
```

Below is my actual code.

```
# create the window to hold the contents
win = GraphWin("Text & Shapes Frenzy", 500, 500)
win.setBackground("Yellow")

#Setting the Title Screen:
title=Text(Point(400,250),"Text & Shapes Frenzy")
title.setFace('arial')
title.setSize(30)
title.setStyle('bold')
title.setFill('White')
title.draw(win)

#Mini-Heading
subheading=Text(Point(400,290), "Click to continue!")
subheading.setFace('courier')
subheading.setSize(22)
subheading.setFill('Blue')
subheading.draw(win)

message=Text(Point(400,50),"""Each click on the next page, adds a new 
shape or text!""")
message.setFace('arial')
message.setSize(24)
message.setStyle('bold')
message.setFill('Red')
message.draw(win)
```

Comment: Sorry! added in my latest attempt, wasn't trying to use this as a free coding service at all, sorry if it came across that way!

Comment: How is that function related to what you're trying to do? It doesn't call `Text()`, it doesn't call `setFace`, `setSize`, `setStyle`, etc.

Comment: You should probably read up on a Python/programming tutorial, for example this one: [Hands-on Python Tutorial - 1. Beginning With Python - 1.11. Defining Functions of your Own](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html)

Comment: Yeah that was like my 8th attempt i tried to use those at the beginning but none worked so then  i kinda just assumed the setSize etc wouldnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
def create_title(x,y,text,face,size,style,fill):
    title=Text(Point(x,y),text)
    title.setFace(face)
    title.setSize(size)
    title.setStyle(style)
    title.setFill(fill)
    title.draw(win)
    return title

title=condense_funtion(400,250,"Text & Shapes Frenzy",.........)
subheading=condense_funtion(.........)
message=condense_funtion(.........)
```

replacing your values when calling the function cheers!

Comment: Ohhhh wow that makes SO much sense, you're literally amazing!!!  thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not the perfect solution but it is just to give you an idea. You can make a function that construct the object for you like this:

```
def set_obj(x=None, y=None, text=None, face=None, size=None, style=None, fill=None, background=None):
    myobj = Text(Point(x,y), text)
    if face:
        myobj.setFace(face)
    if size:
        myobj.setSize(size)
    ...

    return myobj

message = set_obj(x=400, y=500, text='bla bla', face='arial', size=24, style='bold', fill='Red', background=None)
```

Comment: Smart idea, ill play around with this code. Thank you so so much!